# Can we declare a member variable as static for which we are doing constructor injection?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, javabeans

To use a member variable in static function I need to declare that member variable as static. Is there anything wrong in declaring static fields and injecting them via constructor injection in multithreaded environment ?

```
@Named
public class QueryHelper {
  // Anything wrong to declare it static and injecting it via constructor injection ?
   private static QueryUtil queryUtil;

    @Inject
    QueryHelper(final QueryUtil queryUtil) {
        this.queryUtil = queryUtil;
    }

    public static List<Contracts> getContracts() {
       
      // .. some code

       queryUtil.someFunction();


      // ..some code
      return contractList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any (good) reason against making the "static function" to an "instance one"(non-static)? (U can use static "things" .."anywhere":)

Comment: Generally that is an anti-pattern and should be avoided.

Comment: I closed the question as a duplicate and added a few relevant questions to it. The answers/comments on these questions explain why you shouldn't use them.